# After adding a new row in datagridview, display it immediately

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, performance, datagridview

I have a datagridview. When I programmatically add a new row, it should appear immediately on datagridview, instead of waiting to finish all the rows I have.

I was working with the solution below

```
...
adapter.Fill(ds);
foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    datagridView1.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.ColumnName);
}
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    datagridView1.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
...
```

On this solution I have to wait until the `ds.Tables[0].Rows` finishes, and after that the datagridview display those rows.

**I am asking for** for a solution or suggestion where I can see live rows inserting on datagridview, similar with results on SQL Server after executing a query.

Comment: You do realize that this will slow down the rendering of all records? If you want to load in chunks that's fine, but after every row is overkill. For the record, I had a DataGridView years ago that I was loading 30k records into (with about 20 columns) that took under a minute. If I was working on that project again, I would break it down to most likely 1k at a shot, and continue to load until I had everything.

Answer (score 2):

The reason while the rows are not added immediately is the UI thread is busy executing the loop, it has no chance to repaint the UI while the loop has not finished.

Solutions:

1. The old `Application.DoEvents()` "magic" call.

<= There are a lot of people saying `Application.DoEvents` are evil, I can get down votes for this.

Back in the early days of .NET I was really impressed by this magic call. This call pauses the on-going task (adding rows), and executes the pending UI stuffs like repainting the UI, processing mouse/keyboard events. So the UI can remain responsive, otherwise it will be frozen until the lengthy task has finished.

So the code looks like this - Of course, calling it once for each row would be a performance disaster as explained in the comments.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    datagridView1.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
    Application.DoEvents(); 
}
```

2. Use `BeginInvoke`, which accepts a delegate.

The difference between the `BeginInvoke` and directly executing the loop on the UI thread is `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous. Here is [an article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke) explaining `BeginInvoke`. (WOW, I did not expect it has been available since .NET 2.0, a time like a century ago).

[Here is an example of adding rows to DataGridView using BeginInvoke](http://codeissue.com/issues/i24dfacd009a7e4/updating-datagridview-from-different-thread-than-ui-thread).

Comment: this fixes also  selecting new row right after adding row to DatagridView . ArgumentOutOfBoundException due to row not being created immediately. and selecting it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use Databind?

```
private DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
//do what ever
DataRow dataRow = Dt.NewRow();
//add data here to data row
Dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

Though this wont fix you problem with your GUI locking,
 I suggest reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3es4b6yy(VS.71).aspx).